# How can I achieve a "hard-pin" with NPM inside my project?

Tags: npm, dependency-management

I would like to hard-pin my NPM dependencies. "Hard-pinning" would mean that an automated process would check my dependency list for certain packages with certain versions and if a package has been locally upgraded, an custom error message should be shown (ideally, this should be integrated in a pre-push Git hook).

The reasons for wanting this behavior could be:

- external dependencies (e.g. other teams integrating with your project, requiring certain versions)
- broken or unwanted behavior because of certain issues (e.g. "wait until #124 is fixed")
- known non-obvious migration effort for major upgrades
- upgrade incompatibilities (e.g. newest version requires, but does not enforce, a newer peer dependency).

Normal pinning does not cut it in this case: it's trivial to update pinned packages anyway, comments do not work with `package.json` without extra effort and sometimes the reasons are too important not to be displayed explicitly.

How can I achieve such "hard-pinning"?

Comment: Have you tried commiting `package-lock.json` to source control? Also putting exact version numbers would be useful.

Comment: Of course, that's what I meant with "normal pinning". Those version numbers are easily changed and cannot be commented as to why they are pinned to these versions.

Comment: You could arrange a unit test to check those values, a hook in your version control or even check those specific values in your build process after commiting.